# How can I add watermark in all invoice pdf which export for customer order

Tags: magento-1.9, pdf, order-email

I want to add custom text As watermark in order PDF.
I know code is from Here for make PDF But how we can add mask to PDF object?

**app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\Sales\OrderController.php**

```
public function pdfinvoicesAction(){
    $orderIds = $this->getRequest()->getPost('order_ids');
    echo '';print_r($orderIds);exit;
    $flag = false;
    if (!empty($orderIds)) {
        foreach ($orderIds as $orderId) {
            $invoices = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_invoice_collection')
                ->setOrderFilter($orderId)
                ->load();
            if ($invoices->getSize() > 0) {
                $flag = true;
                if (!isset($pdf)){
                    $pdf = Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_invoice')->getPdf($invoices);
                } else {
                    $pages = Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_invoice')->getPdf($invoices);
                    $pdf->pages = array_merge ($pdf->pages, $pages->pages);
                }
            }
        }
        if ($flag) {
            return $this->_prepareDownloadResponse(
                'invoice'.Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s').'.pdf', $pdf->render(),
                'application/pdf'
            );
        } else {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('There are no printable documents related to selected orders.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
```